# Store thousands of files in xcode for iOS app (inside the bundle)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with approx 20,000 image files (animation frames). For a whole bunch of reasons, it's not viable to pack these manually (although ... if I had more time, I would do that).

Xcode slows to a crawl with only a few thousand files, it stops working compeltely (various buttons crash Xcode) when you get to tens of thousands. I've even heard rumours that when you go over 65,535 files, some of the built-in features stop working because someone at Apple used a 16-bit int to store the indexes, sigh.

What options are there for this? It seems there should be some way of telling Xcode "all these files are static binaries that you WILL NEVER TOUCH, put them in a bundle and IGNORE THEM". But googling and reading docs, I can't find any :(

Comment: Someone downvoted the question. Without commenting. That's ... completely unhelpful :(.

Comment: Just a quick question, I assume you use folder references to include the files? Ie they aren't directly listed in the project. I have a suspicion (only) that it might help a lot, but I could be utterly wrong :)

Comment: @theLastNightTrain Folder references have so many bugs - and Apple seems unwilling to support them - that I never use them for anything. They break Apple's build-chain, they break Apple's deployment, they break ... everything :( it seems.

Comment: I use them all the time, and have not noticed problems like that. The only annoyance is sometimes having to do a full clean and delete of simulator app to make sure latest files are copied.

Answer (score 1):

You could save a zipped version in the bundle and unpack that into the application's user directory at runtime. This would only have to be done once.

Comment: Wow, then you end up using storage space for the compressed and uncompressed files, which for 20k images is sure to be quite significant.....

Comment: I thought of this, but given the number of files ... this is going to be very slow on low-end hardware (e.g. iPod Touch). Also, as noted, it's going to greatly increase the on-disk size of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've packed them semi-automatically. I'll explain here in case it helps someone else with the same problem - until/unless someone comes up with a better answer :(

1. Invented my own file format that packs 100's of PNG files into a single file in a way that is FAST to decode
2. Implemented encode/decode methods
3. Wrote a tiny pair of Obj-C methods inside my app (only enabled with a debug switch) that take all the PNG files at runtime, and packs them into N files.
4. Move the first 1,000 files into the project
5. Run the app on simulator, find simulator folder on hard disk (it's in Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhoneSimulator under OS X Mountain Lion with Xcode4.5)
6. Move the "packed" files into the main project
7. Repeat those three steps until done.

It's IMHO a hacky solution - it's depressing that Xcode can't cope with this simple problem that was solved by all the other IDE's about 15 years ago - but it works.

I'm not proud of my pack format, and - given time! - I'd use a standard format and/or write a proper tool for this.

Comment: Why not using a standard `tar` which is exactly doing what you ask for? Its very easy to create and very quick and easy to extract (also partially).

Comment: As far as google knows, there's no TAR library for iOS. And I could only find one decent, documented, C-library - libarchive - but that's very C. Writing a wrapper for obj-c ends up making it take as long to use as rolling your own :(. If you can find a TAR lib ... that would be great :)

Comment: I looked at the TAR protocol too, and it's a lot more verbose than most projects would need. My hacky approach above was a lot less programmer time to implement.